# IIS 7.5 with asp.net mvc webservice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, iis, asmx

what's up?

I'm facing a problem with IIS 7.5 application, asp.net MVC 3 and a set of web services. I created a new web application on port 80 with contains an asp.net mvc web site, that works nice and I need to use the same application to deploy 3 web services (asmx), so I created the following folder structure:

```
-IIS
   - My WebSite (ASP.NET MVC)
      - Services (converted to application)
      - Service 01 (converted to application)
      - Service 02 (converted to application)
      - Service 03 (converted to application)
```

For the services, I'm using a new pool with Identity set for **Network Service** and Authentication for Anonymous Application (configured to use Application pool identity).

I've got the applications working on different sites (two distinct ports), but I need to use the same. Do you have a idea what can I test or to do? Or maybe a clue about it? Any comment is valid for me!

Thanks a lot!

Tiago

Comment: My problem as with asp.net mvc routes. I changed my iis directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this works with web services but consider bindings

http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/mark-newnam/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/